How to Move PHP-FPM Worker Processes to User-Specific SystemD Slices
I'm trying to set up resource limits for users using systemd slices. I created a user slice with this script:
#!/bin/bash
user=$1
user_id=$(id -u "$user")
user_slice="user-${user_id}.slice"

# Set CPU quota for CFS:
systemctl set-property "$user_slice" CPUQuota="20%"
systemctl set-property "$user_slice" CPUQuotaPeriodSec="100ms"
systemctl set-property "$user_slice" MemoryHigh="1G"
systemctl set-property "$user_slice" MemorySwapMax="1G"

The slice works perfectly for processes when users are logged in via SSH. However, with PHP-FPM, these limitations aren't being applied because:

The main PHP-FPM process runs as root Even though PHP-FPM pools run
as the correct user, they don't automatically inherit the user's
slice The PHP-FPM service unit doesn't support dynamic user slices

I have a script that can detect processes belonging to specific users. How can I move these detected PHP-FPM worker processes into their corresponding user slices?
